# How to create a serilog logger file using docker in C# console Application with .Net3.1

Tags: c#, logging, console-application, serilog

I want to create serilog logger file using docker image. I am able to create a file in console app but not able to create using docker.
Here is my sample code,

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File(fileName, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)

                .WriteTo.File(@"C:\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, the docker idea is to isolate the application from the host it is running on. Your app is trying to access the 'c:\log.txt' file which resides on host, not the container. You can write to the file inside the container by specifying the path like '/app/log.txt' (note the linux-style).
If you really need the host-side log file, the more complicated approaches are required - this SO answer may help:

[Expose log file outside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986454/expose-log-file-outside-docker-container)